# How to write $R_{ij}$ as a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

Suppose that $V$ is a vector space of dimension $n$ and $R: V \otimes V \to V \otimes V$ a linear map. Then we can write $R$ as a $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix. Let $R_{ij}: V^{\otimes m} \to V^{\otimes m}$ be the linear map which acts on the $i$-th and $j$-th components of $V^{\otimes m}$ as $R$ and acts on the other components by identity. How to write $R_{ij}$ as a matrix? For example, let $m=3$ and $n=2$. Suppose that $R: V \otimes V \to V \otimes V$ is given by $$ \left(\begin{array}{cccc} -2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -1 & -2 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -2 \end{array}\right). $$ I think that the matrices of $R_{12}, R_{13}, R_{23}$ are $8 \times 8$ matrices. How to write down the matrices of $R_{12}, R_{13}, R_{23}$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, although I'm not sure if it is the easiest or most efficient way, would be use braiding maps. If $i$ and $j$ were adjacent, then the problem would be easily solved by repeatedly making use of the Kronecker product. The fact that $i$ and $j$ may be separated becomes trickier, but nevertheless doable.

First, we calculate $R_{12}$, which is just $R\otimes I$. As a matrix, this is 
$$R_{12} = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} -2I & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -I & -2I & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -I & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -2I \end{array}\right),$$
where $I$ are $2\times 2$ identity matrices, and the $0$s are $2\times 2$ zero matrices. Next, we need a way to move the action of $R$ onto different components. And this is best accomplished using a braiding map which permutes the tensor factors.

Let $T_\sigma$ denote the map with action
$$T_\sigma\left(\otimes_i \mathbf{v}_i\right) = \otimes_i \mathbf{v}_{\sigma(i)},$$
extended linearly. Then $R_{ij}$ would just be
$$R_{ij} = T_{(1i)(2j)}^{-1}\circ R_{12}\circ T_{(1i)(2j)},$$
where $(1i)(2j)$ is the permutation which exchanges $1\leftrightarrow i$ and $2\leftrightarrow j$.

Now, suppose $V$ is $n$-dimensional with basis given by $\{\mathbf{v}_i\}_{i=0}^{n-1}$. Consider the basis $\{\mathbf{v}_{i_1}\otimes \cdots \otimes \mathbf{v}_{i_m}\}$ of $V^{\otimes m}$. Written in terms of column vectors, we will find that 
$$\mathbf{v}_{i_1}\otimes \cdots \otimes \mathbf{v}_{i_m} = \mathbf{e}_{[i_m \cdots i_1]_n},$$
where $\mathbf{e}_j$ denotes the $j$th standard basis vector, and where $[i_m \cdots i_1]_n$ denotes the number given by $i_m \cdots i_1$ in base $n$:
$$[i_m \cdots i_1]_n = \sum_{k=1}^m i_k\cdot n^{k-1}.$$
The action of the braiding map $T_{(1i)(2j)}$ is then
$$T_{(1i)(2j)}\left(\mathbf{e}_{[i_m \cdots i_1]_n}\right) = \mathbf{e}_{[i_m \cdots i_{j+1}i_2i_{j-1}\cdots i_{i+1}i_1i_{i-1}\cdots i_ji_i]_n},$$
which is a handful to write, but should be conceptually clear. For example, to find $R_{23}$, we would need to write down the braiding map $T_{(213)}$, which as a matrix looks like
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Conjugating the $R_{12}$ we found previously by this large permutation matrix will give us $R_{23}$. I will leave this calculation, and the finding of $R_{13}$, to you. Hopefully the method is clear.

Comment: thank you very much. It seems that by your formula $R_{23} = T^{-1}_{(12)(23)} R_{12} T_{(12)(23)}$. We need to compute $T_{(12)(23)} = T_{(123)}$ (but not $T_{(213)}$)?

Comment: in the case of $n=2$ and $m=3$, do you use the following basis of $V \otimes V \otimes V$: $111, 211, 121, 112, 122, 212, 221, 222$ (here $ijk$ means $v_i \otimes v_j \otimes v_k$)?

Comment: @LJR For $R_{23}$, we need a permutation that moves $2 \rightarrow 1$, $3\rightarrow 2$. The only possibility is the permutation $(213)$. I'm multiplying the cycles left to right here, but it's best just to check that it makes sense for the case you need. The basis I'm using is the standard elementary tensor basis (which I will label from $0$ to $2$) ordered lexicographically: 000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111.

Comment: thank you very much for your kind help.